# SQL get records from table where results from another table is in the range defined by Col1 and Col2?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following ranges from a query:

```
Col1 Col2
--------------
100-200
200-300
300-400
```

and this vector from another query:

```
Nbr
----
119
351
149
```

I want to get the ranges for the numbers on the vector.

Is there a way to do this in SQL without recurring to iterations? Something like:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM TB1
WHERE (SELECT Nbr FROM TB2) BETWEEN Col1 and Col2
```

The above query doesn't work because multiple results are returned.

Thank you.

Comment: In the first table (or query result), with Col1 and Col2, are those rows supposed to be in two columns, with no dash (-) between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just use a `join`:

```
SELECT TB1.Col1, TB1.Col2
FROM TB1 JOIN
     TB2
     ON TB2.Nbr BETWEEN TB1.Col1 and TB1.Col2;
```

Comment: Don't you also want to show `TB2.Nbr` in the results, to show which range is "the answer" for which number in the "vector"?

Comment: I just needed the range, but it doesn't hurt to show TB2.Nbr. The answer provided by Gordon Linoff is perfect. Thank you!